# link_to_function in rails 3.1 with blocks throws wrong number of arguments error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I recently started working with rails 3. I'm trying to add a multi-modal form into my application.  I'm following the steps mentioned at [Handle multiple models in one form](http://media.pragprog.com/titles/fr_arr/multiple_models_one_form.pdf)

When I try to add a link via following helper function, I get

> wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Code block below.

```
def add_task_link(name)
    link_to_function name do |page|
        page.insert_html :bottom, :tasks, :partial => 'task' , :object => Task.new
     end
en
```

Googling for solution didn't take me anywhere.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find another tutorial, RJS and prototype are deprecated in rails 3, they've been replaced with jQuery.

If you really insist on going forward, you can bring RJS and prototype back by adding the following to your `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'prototype-rails'
```

This will bring back the [correct version](https://github.com/rails/prototype-rails/blob/v0.3.1/lib/prototype-rails/javascript_helper.rb#L56) of `link_to_function`.